# can't pass argument to event listener

Tags: symfony

Using Symfony 2.5.3. I'm trying to send a 'welcome' e-mail when someone has succesfully registered(FOS Userbunde), using an EventListener. The event fired is `fos_user.registration.success`.

So I added a service:

```
mycustom_user.registration_success:
    class: Mycustom\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
    arguments: [@mycustom_user.mailer]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: fos_user_registration_success, method: onRegistrationSuccess}
```

The listener itself:

```
namespace Mycustom\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Mycustom\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $mailer;

    public function __construct(Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }


    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getForm()->getData();

        $this->mailer->sendWelcomeMessage($user);

        $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_security_login');
        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
    }
}
```

The mailer itself contains the rendering of the content of the email, also registered as a service:

```
mycustom_user.mailer:
    class: Mycustom\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer
    arguments: ['@templating']
```

`mycustom_user.mailer` is argument for the listener. But somehow I keep getting this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to 
Mycustom\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener::__construct() 
must be an instance of Mycustom\UserBundle\Mailer\Mailer, none given, 
called in mycustom/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php 
on line 2214 and defined in mycustom/src/Mycustom/UserBundle/EventListener/RegistrationListener.php line 19
```

I tried other arguments like @doctrine (and changed the listeners constructor accordingly), but I keep getting the same error. Also the @templating argument to the mailer service doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you in `dev` env (request via `app_dev.php`)? Additionally you could try clear cache (ex. `rm -rf app/cache/*`).

Comment: Yes, I request via app_dev.php. I empty cache with ```app/console cache:clear --no-debug```

Comment: For starters, your tag should be kernel.event_subscriber since you are implementing the subscriber interface.  I'm guessing that the code you posted is not your actual code?

Comment: thanks, changed it to `kernel.event_subscriber`, but didn't solve it. Actually the code is pretty complete. I did change the vendor part (Mycustom is actually something else). I added the method `onRegistrationSuccess` for completeness

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem that I had was that I had two listeners in one class. And the 2nd service definition didn't contain the argument for the constructor. Should be like this:

```
mycustom_user.registration_initialize:
    class: Mycustom\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
    arguments: ['@mycustom_user.mailer']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, alias: mycustom_user_registration_listener}

mycustom_user.registration_success:
    class: Mycustom\UserBundle\EventListener\RegistrationListener
    arguments: ['@mycustom_user.mailer']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```